# About the Box and Product topologies

Tags: general-topology

I would like to ask a question about the interiors related to topologies taken on Product.
Let $\{i:i\in I\}$ be any infinite index set and $A_{i}\subseteq X_{i}$. And $\prod_{i\in I} X_{i}$ be the product space with the Product topology. I know that the statement $\prod_{i\in I} int(A_{i})=int(\prod_{i\in I} A_{i})$ does not always hold. But if we take the BOX topology on $\prod_{i\in I} X_{i}$. Then equality holds. Now that the elements of the box topology is the form of $\prod_{i\in I} U_{i}$ where $U_{i}$ is open in $X_{i}$, then all this $U_{i}$ must be proper open subset of $X_{i}$ ? otherwise the equality does not hold for the box topology too?

Comment: The fact that the product of the interiors is the interior of the product set is typical for the box topology (and holds there regardless of what the $A_i$ are). It almost *never* holds in infinite standard products.

Comment: Thank you so much for that sir. @HennoBrandsma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but what you're saying is correct. When considering $\prod_i X_i$, we can endow it either with the box topology or the product topology. Unless the indexing set is finite, these will give you different topologies.

The box topology is indeed characterised by the fact that the interior of a product $\prod_i A_i \subseteq \prod_i X_i$ will be $\prod_i \operatorname{Int}(A_i)$. This is not the case in the product topology. Indeed, if infinitely many of the $A_i$ are *proper* subspaces of $X_i$, then $\prod_i \operatorname{Int}(A_i)$ will not even be an open subset with respect to the product topology.

In the case that infinitely many of the $A_i$ are proper subspaces of $X_i$, do you have an idea what the interior of $\prod_i A_i$ will be with respect to the product  topology? The answer may surprise you!

Comment: It worth mentioning that $\displaystyle\overline{\Pi_i A_i}=\displaystyle{\Pi_{i}\overline{A_i}}$ in the product topology.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answeer. I think I got my answer, and I guess the interior will be empty set? @JernenvanderMeer

Comment: That is correct :-)

Comment: thank you for the answer :) @JeroenvanderMeer